# Librería ´Taxize´ Error in names(key_helpers) <- keynames[1:2] : 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Quiero realizar una búsqueda masiva de especies en la base de datos de **Tropicos** y **col** a partir de la función *synonyms* de Taxize. Para esto tengo el siguiente código:

```
library("taxize")
df.spe <- read.csv() # El archivo puede descargarse de https://tools.bgci.org/global_tree_search.php, el que uso es el 1.5

col.name.list <- list()
tropicos.name <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(df.spe))
{
  r2 <- try(synonyms(df.spe$TaxonName[i],db= 'col',rows = 1), silent = T)
  r1 <- synonyms(df.spe$TaxonName[i],db= "tropicos",rows = 1)
  
  col.name.list[[i]] <- r2
  tropicos.name[[i]] <- r1
  
  rm(r1);rm(r2)
  
}
```

Al correrlo me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error in names(key_helpers) <- keynames[1:2] :
> 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Al utilizar la función *try* con el parámetro `silent = T` en ambas bases de datos, efectivamente realiza la búsqueda pero todas aparecen con el mismo error.

Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conocía este paquete, pero me interesa su función así que intenté obtener los registros que buscas y noté cosas extrañas en tu script.

De acuerdo a la documentación del paquete taxize (ver. 0.9.99) el argumento **db** de la función `synonyms()` debe de ser uno de itis, tropicos, nbn, worms, ó pow. Por lo que cuando usas *col*  como su valor, este argumento no se usa y me parece que se usa "nbn" en su lugar, cosa que puede no ser lo que quieres.

Otra cosa que noté es que no especificas es si estás usando la llave para el API de tropicos como recomienda la documentación. Yo no tengo ese registro así que no pude verificar esa solución, pero deberías revisar si es ese el problema. Para usar la llave para tropicos, puedes usar las instrucciones y enlace al que lleva la función `use_tropicos()`: ya que obtengas tu llave debes incluirla en .Renviron , puedes hacer esto con usethis::edit_r_environ(), agregando TROPICOS_KEY='pon aqui la llave' y reiniciando R. Sospecho que ese es problema porque cuando uso otras bases de datos que no sean tropicos (como nbn, itis, worms) no obtengo el problema.

Como última nota, noté que también es posible hacer la búsqueda de todo un vector de caracteres de nombres de especies, dependiendo de lo que quieres, puede no ser necesario el ciclo. Usando solo las primeras 8 especies del archivo que mencionas usando:

```
library("taxize")
df.spe <- read.csv("especies_1_5.csv")  
x <- df.spe$TaxonName
sinonimos <- synonyms(x, db= 'nbn', rows = 1)
sinonimos
```

puedo obtener algunos registros de la base de datos nbn:

```
    > sinonimos
$`Abarema abbottii`
[1] NA

$`Abarema acreana`
[1] NA

$`Abarema adenophora`
# A tibble: 0 x 0

$`Abarema alexandri`
         nameString                               nameComplete
1 Echinus alexandri Echinus alexandri Danielssen & Koren, 1883
                                                                                                                                           nameFormatted
1 <span class="scientific-name rank-species"><span class="name">Echinus alexandri</span> <span class="author">Danielssen &amp; Koren, 1883</span></span>
          nameGuid nomenclaturalCode taxonomicStatus nomenclaturalStatus
1 NHMSYS0020498842                NA         synonym                  NA
  nameAccordingTo nameAccordingToID namePublishedIn namePublishedInYear
1              NA                NA              NA                  NA
  namePublishedInID nameAuthority taxonRemarks infoSourceURL datasetURL
1                NA          UKSI           NA            NA         NA

$`Abarema asplenifolia`
              nameString             nameComplete
1           Barbula rufa Barbula rufa (Lor.) Jur.
2 Didymodon asperifolius   Didymodon asperifolius
                                                                                                                     nameFormatted
1 <span class="scientific-name rank-species"><span class="name">Barbula rufa</span> <span class="author">(Lor.) Jur.</span></span>
2                               <span class="scientific-name rank-species"><span class="name">Didymodon asperifolius</span></span>
          nameGuid nomenclaturalCode taxonomicStatus nomenclaturalStatus
1 NBNSYS0000142766                NA         synonym                  NA
2 NBNSYS0000146085                NA         synonym                  NA
  nameAccordingTo nameAccordingToID namePublishedIn namePublishedInYear
1              NA                NA              NA                  NA
2              NA                NA              NA                  NA
  namePublishedInID nameAuthority taxonRemarks infoSourceURL datasetURL
1                NA          UKSI           NA            NA         NA
2                NA          UKSI           NA            NA         NA

$`Abarema auriculata`
# A tibble: 0 x 0

$`Abarema barbouriana`
              nameString           nameComplete
1 Pinnularia balfouriana Pinnularia balfouriana
                                                                                       nameFormatted
1 <span class="scientific-name rank-species"><span class="name">Pinnularia balfouriana</span></span>
          nameGuid nomenclaturalCode taxonomicStatus nomenclaturalStatus
1 NBNSYS0100014377                NA         synonym                  NA
  nameAccordingTo nameAccordingToID namePublishedIn namePublishedInYear
1              NA                NA              NA                  NA
  namePublishedInID nameAuthority taxonRemarks infoSourceURL datasetURL
1                NA          UKSI           NA            NA         NA

$`Abarema barnebyana`
[1] NA

attr(,"class")
[1] "synonyms"
attr(,"db")
[1] "nbn"
```

Ojala sirva como punto de inicio